# Building Model object from multiple rest calls

Tags: ember.js, rsvp.js

I have a route like following where it builds the data from multiple rest calls.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
      var id = 1; //will get as url param later
      var modelData = {ab:{},ef:{}};
        return ajaxPromise('https://url1/'+ id +'?order=desc').then(function(data){
            modelData.ab = data.items[0];
            return ajaxPromise('https://url2/'+ id +'/?order=desc').then(function(data){
                modelData.ab.x = data.items;
                return modelData;
            })
        });
    }
});
```

My ajaxPromise function is as follows:

```
var ajaxPromise = function(url, options){
  return Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var options = options || {
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsonp'
    };

    options.success = function(data){
      resolve(data);
    };

    options.error = function(jqXHR, status, error){
      reject(arguments);
    };

    Ember.$.ajax(url, options);
  });
};
```

Now the issue is i know that i can use RSVP.all with promise instances but the data returned from these url has to be set to model object like above.

Also there may be few more rest calls which require data from other rest call. Is there any other way i can handle this promises.

PS: data is required right away for a single route

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
      var id = 1; //will get as url param later
      return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        r1: ajaxPromise('https://url1/'+ id +'?order=desc'),
        r2: ajaxPromise('https://url2/'+ id +'/?order=desc')
      });
   },
  setupController:function(controller, model){
    model.ab = model.r1.items[0];
    model.ab.x = model.r2.items;
    this._super(controller, model);
  }
);
```

If you have two that have to run synchronously(second depends on first), you can create your own promise, which eon't resolve until you call resolve.

```
   model: function() {
      var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var modelData = {ab:{},ef:{}};
        ajaxPromise('https://url1/'+ id +'?order=desc').then(function(data){
          modelData.ab = data.items[0];
          ajaxPromise('https://url2/'+ id +'/?order=desc').then(function(data){
            modelData.ab.x = data.items;
            resolve(modelData);
          })
        });
      });
     return promise;
   },
```

Comment: wow..awesome..BTW one more doubt not cleared..there are some rest calls which should wait for result from some other rest call..how can I handle this?

Comment: create your own promise, see above.